# Rust closures which mutate captured variables

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a function which converts a graph to acyclic. I have this code working in Python which uses a `dfs` function which takes two functions: one to run before visiting the node, and one to run afterwards. This has worked nicely in Python and I want the same interface in rust.

The code I currently have is:

```
    fn make_acyclic (
        &self,
    ) -> Graph<E> {
        let mut dag_nodes = HashMap::new();
        let mut finish_times = HashMap::new();
        let mut t = 0;

        let pre_fn = |node: &E| {
            t += 1;
            dag_nodes.insert(node, node.clone());
        };

        let post_fn = |node: &E| {
            t += 1;
            finish_times.insert(node, t);
        };

        let mut visited = HashSet::new();
        self.dfs_from(&self.root, &mut visited, Some(&pre_fn), Some(&post_fn));
        ...
```

where the borrow checker complains that I'm borrowing `t` as mutable twice. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Either use a [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) or an [`Atomic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

So you very definitely *are* borrowing `t` as mutable twice - you have two things which store a mutable reference to `t`, which, if I'm understanding, will be mutating it in an interleaved way.

You'll want to use one of the shared mutable containers - see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html

Comment: Is there a reason why I can't just use `Cell`?

Comment: `Rc<RefCell>` and `Arc<Mutex>` are both overkill here. If the code is multi-thread, `Arc<Atomic…>` is better suited. If the code is single thread, then either `Rc<Cell>`, or more probably `Cell` are the right choice (actually `&Cell` since the closures borrow by default).

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, but from https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html my understanding is that `Cell` will not let you use mutable references, which I think are essentially what you want for your `+=` syntax. You should be able to implement the same logic with either, but I think that with `Cell` you could more easily create an immutable copy rather than mutate the shared value.

Comment: With `Cell` you will need to do `t.set (t.get() + 1)`, but the performance impact is much less than with `RefCell`: `Cell` is almost free, its only impact is that it prevents some compiler optimizations, in particular there are no runtime checks, it's all done at compile time. `RefCell` is intended for use when the value isn't `Copy` and does require runtime checks.

Comment: Fair - edited my answer to just point to the documentation on `Cell`/`RefCell`.